# Remove white spaces when drawing a figure with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, canvas, plot

This is driving me nuts.

Using matplotlib in python,
I am drawing a simple plot (twenty pixels of different color) as follows:

```
fig1, ax = plt.subplots()
color_rgb_list = np.random.rand(n_colors, 3)
ax.imshow(color_rgb_list[None, :], aspect='equal')
for label in train_y:
    ax.text(label - 1.5, 1, str(label))
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
# fig1.savefig("test.png", bbox_inches='tight')
```

However, the result I get has a lot of white space around it. I found out that I can use `bbox_inches='tight'` when actually saving the figure to a file, however that does not really help me, as instead I would like to remove the white spaces while drawing the actual image.
(I am using this for an app, where I want to display several different plots in one window using **tkinter** with `.pack()`)

[image: This is the results I get: when drawing/showing my plot. Instead I would like to remove all white spaces, especially at the top/bottom]

How can I remove the white spaces when drawing/showing my plot?
I would basically like to achieve the same thing that `bbox_inches='tight'` does, only when using `plt.show()`, or when drawing on canvas using **tkinter**.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're making such an irregular-sized plot, you can specify a `figsize` **kwarg that will stretch the window accordingly.

```
fig1, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 2)) # figsize = (width, height)
color_rgb_list = np.random.rand(n_colors, 3)
ax.imshow(color_rgb_list[None, :], aspect='equal')
for label in train_y:
    ax.text(label - 1.5, 1, str(label))
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

see if playing with that helps

Comment: i have already played with that, unfortunately without success... but thanks. any other ideas?

Comment: I actually got this to work, not sure why it was not working before, thanks a lot, i feel bit like an idiot. thanks again!

Comment: I'm still getting a thin white border around the figure when I run exactly that code.  @SimonMayrshofer did you ever figure out what the issue is?